# Number next to a particular answer seems to be incorrect

Tags: support, reputation, specific-answer, score

User [mk1505](https://superuser.com/users/63399/mk1505?tab=reputation) has posted a single answer on SuperUser. On [his reputation page](https://superuser.com/users/63399/mk1505?tab=reputation) we can see that he has received two upvotes for his answer. The first on Jan 17 '11, the second on Mar 7 '12. He has not received any downvotes. That is why I would think that the number displayed next to [his answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1862/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-the-graphics-card-in-modern-laptops/233970#233970) should be **2**. But it is only **1**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer has 2 upvotes and 1 downvote, see the [post timeline](https://superuser.com/posts/1862/timeline).

The downvote was given when `mk1505` had 1 rep, which you can never go below and thus the -2 'disappeared'.

Comment: Also, you can find this information yourself in the [timeline](http://superuser.com/posts/1862/timeline).

Comment: @animuson: which is where I got my confirmation about the vote tally from. :-)

Comment: @animuson & MartijnPieters Thank you. By the way, I was completely unaware of the timeline feature. Thanks for sharing.